# Search youtube channel for specific video id's

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a large array of video id's. (Over 100) I need to determine which videos belong to the oauth'd user. Looking through the Youtube API docs it doesn't look like they have a way to get videos by ID for a channel. I see how to get all videos for a channel but that looks like it limits the results. Is there an efficient way to do this that I'm missing?

Ideally I'd like to say grab all videos with this id that belong to this channel. I'd accept a way to just get all videos for the users channel so I can compare the array of videos with my array of id's.

Using Laravel socialite and the PHP google api client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1. Get videos by IDs using the [videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint. The `id` parameter takes up to 50 comma-separated videoIDs.

or

2. Get all videos in a channel using the [channels:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint. The `id` parameter takes up to 50 comma-separated channelIDs. Each page of results has up to 50 videos.

If you already have the videoIDs, option 1 would be best.

Comment: The problem I run into with either is having more then 50 videos. If I have 500 video id's and the channel has 300 video id's. Those wouldn't work.

Comment: Either would work. For 1, just request 50 at a time until you have them all. For 2, request the next page until you have them all.

Comment: You're right. They would work. Just not as efficient as I was hoping. Without anything better I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out if you want to get the video with particular video id

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcMzwMrr1tE
```

if you want the thumbnails for the particular video

https://storage.googleapis.com/yt-trends-top-ten-lists-2022/thumbs/**hcMzwMrr1tE**.jpg

put the video id you will get the details you can use google api like this